# Radio button doesnt work inside css accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I have a radio button inside a css accordion and for some reason it doesnt work.  Maybe the css I'm using for the accordion is overriding the radio button?  maybe because the accordion is made from a check box that is causing problems? I've also put dojo controls inside the accordion and some work, some don't Below is the code:   The first radio button outside the accordion works fine

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="green" />Green <!--this works fine-->
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="red" />Red
<section id="accordionMTF">
    <div>
        <div style="width: 450px;
                              height: 80px"></div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkMTF-1" checked="checked" />
        <label for="checkMTF-1">Input System Info</label>
        <article>
            <input type="radio" name="colors" value="green" />Green  <!--this doesnt work-->
            <input type="radio" name="colors" value="red" />Red</article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkMTF-2" />
        <label for="checkMTF-3">Input Marking Information</label>
        <article>
            <p style="width: 450px;
                              height: 400px">Fill out form</p>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkMTF-3" />
        <label for="checkMTF-4">Complete and Submit</label>
        <article>
            <p style="width: 450px;
                              height: 400px">Fill out form</p>
        </article>
    </div>
</section>
```

css:
/*Mark Ticket Form Accordion*/

```
#accordionMTF input {
        display: none;
    }
    #accordionMTF label {
        background: #eee;
        border-radius: .25em;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: .125em;
        padding: .25em 1em;
        z-index: 20;
    }
    #accordionMTF label:hover {
        background: #ccc;
    }
    #accordionMTF input:checked + label {
        background: #ccc;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
        color: white;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    #accordionMTF article {
        background: #f7f7f7;
        height:0px;
        overflow:hidden;
        z-index:10;
    }
    #accordionMTF article p {
        padding: 1em;
    }
    #accordionMTF input:checked article {
    }
    #accordionMTF input:checked ~ article {
        border-bottom-left-radius: .25em;
        border-bottom-right-radius: .25em;
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: .125em;
    }
```

I have a fiddle:
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/czo2m22s/15/)

Thanks

Comment: your radiobox are hidden via css: `#accordionMTF input { display: none }`. You should also use a different name (`colors` was already used)

Comment: when you say "it doesnt work" do you mean to say "it doesnt show up"? because your css clearly hides it `#accordionMTF input {display: none;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer of you accordion has decided to hide ALL inputs (!?)

```
#accordionMTF input {
    display: none;
}
```

A more sane approach would be to give the inputs that are required for the accordion functionality a class (`.hidden`) and use that as a selector instead of blanket hidding all inputs:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="hidden" id="checkMTF-1" class="hidden" />

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/czo2m22s/18/)

Answer (score 1):

So long as you continue to use the same HTML structure, all you need to do is rework your css a little bit. The follow css

```
#accordionMTF input {
    display: none;
}
```

Needs to look like this

```
#accordionMTF > div > input[type='checkbox'] {
    display : none;
}
```

This is an excellent attempt to create an accordion without javascript. You might also consider incorporating CSS3 animations.

There is also a bug where your labels have the wrong `for` attribute value.

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/czo2m22s/21/

Answer (score 0):

here is the reason:

```
accordionMTF input {
        display: none;
    }
```